# A word for feeling simultaneously happy & sad

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means feeling both happy and sad at the same time. Here's a sentence I'd like to use it in:

> "At least we got one vote," she said with a (word I'm looking for) smile.

Comment: I can't answer here, but I think the answer is wistful. "having or showing a feeling of vague or regretful longing.
"a wistful smile"". If you upvote my comment I can answer haha

Answer (score 31):

[Bittersweet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bittersweet):

> - producing or expressing a mixture of pain and pleasure: a movie with a bittersweet ending.
> - pleasant but tinged with sadness.

- a bittersweet smile.

(TFD)

Comment: it doesn't fit to the OP's example though, does it?

Answer (score 10):

While somewhat broader than happy/sad, you could say ambivalent.

Having mixed feelings or contradictory ideas about something or someone:

> Some loved her, some hated her, few were ambivalent about her.

Answer (score 8):

The dictionary on my Mac defines *rueful* as

> expressing sorrow or regret, especially in a wry or humorous way: she
>   gave a rueful grin

which fits OP's sentence quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Melancholic! Bittersweet more exact.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what the OP's looking for but *tragicomic* also describes both happy and sad feelings at the same time.

> **Tragicomic (adj):** Something that is tragicomic is both sad and amusing at the same time.
>
> Example: This was a tragicomic story of human frailty.

— [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tragicomic)

Or *ambivalent*.

> **Ambivalent (adj):** Having mixed feelings or contradictory ideas about something or someone.
>
> Example: an ambivalent attitude to Europe.

— [Lexico](http://Having%20mixed%20feelings%20or%20contradictory%20ideas%20about%20something%20or%20someone.)

Answer (score 0):

"At least we got one vote," she said with a **wan** smile.

You could also use **feeble**.