# Word or phrase for the beauty in pain, tragedy, damage, etc?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, loanwords, foreign-phrases

I'm looking for either a single word or a very short (really, as short as possible) phrase that could be defined (literally or metaphorically) as:

"beauty that is possessed due to or despite the pain, suffering, darkness, brokenness, disturbing qualities, malformation, etc. belonging to the entity in question."

It does not necessarily need to reference any of those (traditionally) negative qualities explicitly; you can replace them with a blanket statement such as "a quality that is traditionally viewed as negative or in opposition to wellness."

The word/phrase could be in English or any other language. If it is in a language other than English, it will still be used in the context of English as a loan-word.

The word/phrase does not need to literally mean this; even if it refers to this concept only in metaphor I will accept it.

This word or phrase does not need to be in formal usage or be in a traditional dictionary. What I mean by this is that the word may be one that is found only in a particular literary or scholarly work(s), or is in common parlance. Therefore, slang is acceptable, as is a word that is only seen in a specialized academic community, or even a word made up by a well known and reputable writer. I don't want nonsense words you make up.

An example sentence illustrating the intended usage is "She [a horribly scarred young woman] possessed a profound and unsettling _____."

An adjectival form of this idea would also be acceptable, in which case an example sentence could be "The ______ scene filled the explorers with unexpected awe."

Note that the word or phrase need not obey the specific structure of those sentences, as they were supplied simply to illustrate the general direction of usage.

Comment: 'French'. The word is 'French'

Comment: [bittersweet](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bittersweet) (adjective) - both pleasant and painful or regretful

Comment: Bittersweet is not specific enough, as it could refer to many qualities other than beauty. Also, saying "bittersweet beauty" would most likely be interpreted as a beauty you enjoy but is also painful. That is also not specific enough, though I suppose potentially applicable. It is important to note that the beauty itself is not necessarily painful (to the person perceiving the beauty); the possessor of the beauty is the one who may be in pain. An important distinction. Thank you anyways.

Comment: I like "tortured beauty," however it is somewhat constrained (constrained to cases of the subject being in pain or appearing as if they are); I need something which is inclusive of other types of qualities (along the lines of what I specified in the original post).

Comment: Hi Naomi, please keep in mind that a very similar [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/228000/a-word-for-feeling-simultaneously-happy-sad) already exists. That said, depending on the cause of the pain, and how intense you wish to portray it, 'melancholic' or 'melancholy' can be used as well. Observing the range of situations you are looking for a word for (from awesome sight to scarred woman), I am not sure if such a words exists, purely based on how each situation might have a different root cause, With different root causes, often different words are used due to connotation.

Comment: For example, in case of the 'a profound and unsettling ____', you'd need a word fit in with both 'profound' and 'unsettling'. Since 'profoundly unsettling' is already an expression to describe a certain feeling or emotion, I feel it is difficult to use them together to describe another feeling or emotion altogether. Of course, I might just be lacking the correct words in my vocabulary ^^.

Comment: Hi Terah, this question is distinct from the question you linked to in that the question you linked to discusses simultaneous happiness and sadness, while this question does not have any direct implication of happiness. "Bittersweet" and "melancholic" are not suitable terms for this concept due to the fact that they imply the emotional response of sorrow (and in the case of the former, happiness), while the concept is only about the perception of beauty. Those words also could imply that the entity in question is emotionally charged, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: The only significant factors of this concept are the traditionally perceived aversive qualities of the entity in question and the beauty in it perceived. The situations I described are similar in that they share this quality: the scars on the woman are considered signs of damage and a disturbing past event, and yet the viewer perceives beauty in her; the scene that inspired awe could be the aftermath of terrible destruction, in which case it is unsettling and embodying damage, and yet still filled the viewer with awe at its inadvertent beauty. Both are profoundly unsettling.

Comment: I would like to say the scope may be huge, but the concept is a unified one. It is a quality of experience that extends across cultures. The Japanese language has a term, "wabi-sabi," which is the beauty in imperfection, as seen in deteriorating buildings or objects. The reason this term doesn't fit properly is that it is used to refer to the beauty in transience (the initial perfection of a creation fails but it is still beautiful), whereas this is a larger concept of beauty in the traditionally aversive. This includes things such as a pained person, or inflicted damage.

Comment: The Greek tragedies are another example of this. They were designed to be beautiful through the pain and sorrow of the story. There are numerous writings on this. In modern art movements, beauty is often shown through what we would traditionally consider imperfections and deformity. This is a widespread phenomenon, perhaps an integral part to human experience. Due to its ever present nature, and the fact that it is contained within a central theme, I feel as if there should be a word or concise phrase to describe it. Someone must have come up with one.

Comment: Mitch!  French.  Probably the best answer I've ever read.  But, as you can suspect, I can't give you a point.  While it answers the question precisely, it would never play in prose.

Comment: I've recently been searching for the mentioned description. One who finds beauty wholly in pain or sadness. I find that sadistic would be close but its not admirance more so than finding a twisted joy in one's suffering. Searching other languages might prove profitable, many poetic devices are used in various ways, each culture with their own unique expressions. Japanese would be my first searching point, however tedious it would prove... I am sure that there should be an equivalent in the english vocabulary, however I have yet to find it... This is somewhat frustrating..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Tortured beauty"** comes to mind, although you mention in your comment that you find it "constrained to cases of the subject being in pain or appearing as if they are." So onward,

> "There was no guile there, no artifice or coquetry, just that **terrible aching beauty**. -Paul Adam, *A Nasty Dose of Death* from http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/coquetry

or

> "Such **aching beauty**, at the cost of solitude." from https://www.foboko.com/sentence-dictionary/english/solitude

or

> "The mind passes, the eye closes, the spirit is a passage; The beauty of things was born before eyes and sufficient to itself; The **heart-breaking beauty** will remain when there is no heart to break for it. -Robinson Jeffers, Tor House, Carmel, October 1, 1927" from "Credo" in *The Women at Point Sur,* page 239 at http://tinyurl.com/zklw6ko

or

> "All changed, changed utterly;
>   A **terrible beauty** is born. 
>   W.B. Yeats – Easter 1916, from http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/beauty

If I can think of others, I will edit them into my answer.

Comment: Reading these additional phrases you have come across leads me to a greater understanding of the first to come to your mind, as well as what I should be seeking out in general. I was at first trying to find a word (or short phrase) to use as a sort of stand in for the concept as a whole, a piece of nomenclature which could simply be put down to reference something much larger. I now realize that you are presenting a different approach- characterizing it indirectly.

Comment: What I mean by that is that instead of describing the aspects of that which is considered beautiful, or any personal emotional connection to that subject, the beauty itself is characterized as something separate than generic beauty, and in doing so the possessor of the beauty is described indirectly, by implication. The beauty itself is personified and given characteristics of effect. The quote from Robinson Jeffers encapsulates the idea nicely: the beauty and its powerful affect exist independent from the perceiver.

Comment: So, one simply must come up with an adequate portrayal of the beauty- and I think such phrases as "terrible beauty" do a very good job at attempting this. Though this is not quite a perfect answer for the original interpretation of the question, it works and answers the question in a different respect, so I will mark it as the solution. I will consider the options you've presented and perhaps, or perhaps not, continue my search with new eyes. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Naomi- Thank you for accepting my answer while still seeking the perfect word or phrase. The Jeffers quote is a hand-written inscription on the front fly-leaf of my signed copy of the book, which suggests its importance to the author. The depth of your questions and comments and your facility with language make you a most welcome addition to the EL&U community.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you're looking for is ***pathos***:

> the quality or power in an actual life experience or in literature, music, speech, or other forms of expression, of evoking a feeling of pity, or of sympathetic and kindly sorrow or compassion. (from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pathos))

The adjectival form of *pathos* is *pathetic*, which has less power in this context, since it is used far more commonly as a descriptor of a wholly negative quality, so perhaps *poignant* would be a more appropriate adjective.

Comment: That is a very elegant solution, however somewhat astray from what I am seeking. Pity, sympathy, or compassion are all aligned with this concept, however none express the important idea of *beauty.* You may well feel sympathy or compassion for the entity possessing the quality I'm seeking out, however the perceived beauty is separate from such feelings and is the focus of this concept. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Given the scope of the question, I too feel that 'pathos' is more of a concept unrelated, or only applicable to a small section, of what the OP is looking for. Depending on why the word is sought (for example a novel), the feeling might be better of being described, rather than consensed to a singular word or abbreviation of what could be a mental image creating description of how the characters are feeling :)

Comment: To answer Terah's proposition of a full description: The usage (a name/title for a particular thing which I won't specify here) actually dictates that this concept is represented by a singular word or very short phrase.